# "KeyError: 0" when connecting to MySQL (get_default_isolation_level)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Currently developing for python 3.9.6 with sqlalchemy version 1.4.23 and whenever I use sqlalchemy to connect to a database, I get an error with this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Importer/common/db.py", line 106, in db_cur
    with engine.connect() as con:
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3166, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3245, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3212, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 307, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 767, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 425, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 253, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 368, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 622, in __connect
    pool.dispatch.connect.for_modify(
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 329, in _exec_w_sync_on_first_run
    self(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 343, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1691, in go
    return once_fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 674, in first_connect
    dialect.initialize(c)
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2961, in initialize
    default.DefaultDialect.initialize(self, connection)
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 407, in initialize
    self.default_isolation_level = self.get_default_isolation_level(
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 473, in get_default_isolation_level
    return self.get_isolation_level(dbapi_conn)
  File "/home/jimmy/.local/share/virtualenvs/Importer-0-6a4YAh/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2720, in get_isolation_level
    val = row[0]
KeyError: 0
```

I can fix the issue by manually changing the file from
`val = row[0]`
to
`val = row['@@transaction_isolation']`
but I don't want to have to manually change dependency files after installing them. I have tried manually setting the transaction isolation when creating the engine, but that doesn't prevent get_isolation_level() from being called so the error persists. Is sqlalchemy not compatible with python 3.9.6? Does this have anything to do with the mysql server version?

Comment: What driver (DBAPI layer) are you using? In other words, what is "xxx" in "mysql+xxx://…" for your connection URI?

Comment: I wasn't specifying one, per documentation 'mysql-python' is the default one

Comment: You can check for sure with `print(engine.dialect.driver)`.

Comment: DBAPI is `mysqldb`

Comment: Okay, so `mysql+mysqldb://` is indeed the default driver and it is very widely used. Now check the actual connection URI that you are using. Does it make any mention of "cursorclass" or "DictCursor"?

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I am using a DictCursor, which was set up to change _fetch_type to allow sqlalchemy to check for things like `@@transaction_isolation` during the initial connection. I recently updated the mysql server, though, and was only changing the fetch type for `SELECT @@tx_isolation` instead of `SELECT @@transaction_isolation`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with the DictCursor being used in the connection. Changing _fetch_type for `SELECT @@transaction_isolation` to be a tuple instead of a dictionary solved the issue.